# Enabling auto migration at an Identity Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using .NET MVC 5 to create an application. I'm using the code first approach. I have a separated assembly to put my database classes, and have separated my context in different migrations folders. So far I have 2 contexts, and one is the IdentityDb that inherits from IdentityDbContext.
So far, so good. But when I try to enable auto migrations (because I still don't have an production version and an auto migration will not hurt), something bad happens at IdentityDb. This is how I enabled the Auto Migration:

```
public class IdentityDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public IdentityDb() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<IdentityDb, Configuration>("DefaultConnection"));
    }
}
```

Of Course I have the Configuration class, with the seed method, and AutomaticMigrationsEnabled property set to true. Everything seems fine, but when I try to do something that needs the Identity context (such as login), I get this error message:

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized
```

The line it says there is the error is at:

```
public IdentityDb() : base("DefaultConnection")
```

But it is. I assume that when I pass it as "DefaultConnection" at the base constructor and when instantiating the  MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion, the connection string is set.

Finally, I want to say that this only happen at IdentityDb context. I have auto migrations enabled in my other context, CampaignsDb, exactly the same way, and it works perfectly.  Does anyone have an idea about what's happening with the IdentityDb? Is the problem because this class inherits the IdentityDbContext, and the auto migrations should be enabled with a different approach?

Comment: don't know if it helps, but remove the `"DefaultConnection"` from `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`. You already have your configuration type passed in, which in turn should be using your `DBContext`. This is just an assumption worth trying

Comment: @dima Wow, you are absolutely right! Removed it and it worked perfectly. Wonder why passing the connection string when invoking the base class and when instantianting the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion works with other contexts, but not with the one derived from IdentityDbContex.
Do you want to write your solution as an answer so I can mark it as answer or do you prefer me to write it in this thread?

Comment: cool, glad it worked. I added an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `"DefaultConnection"` from `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`. You already have your configuration type passed in, which in turn should be using your DBContext. So it would be like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<IdentityDb, Configuration>());
```